# Polymer element blur event

Tags: polymer

I am trying to see what is easy to do with polymer and am having a hard time getting the seemingly simplest events to fire.

```
<polymer-element name="field" attributes=" type name value">
  <template>
    <label>{{name}}
      <input  type={{type}} name={{name}} value={{value}}>
    </label>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('field', {
      onblur: function () {
        console.log('blurred');
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I have created this element and want to do something on blur does anyone know what I am missing or where in the docs I should be looking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `name="field"` doesn't match `Polymer('profile-field'`, but I assume that's just some kind of typo.
2. `blur` events do not bubble, so your input blurring is not going to result in a `blur` event on your host element.
3. it's best not to override `on<event>` functions, you are better off using Polymer event binding.

I'm not sure if this is actually what you are after, but here is an example that listens to blur on the input itself.

```
<polymer-element name="profile-field" attributes="type name value">
  <template>
    <label>{{name}}
      <input on-blur="{{inputBlur}}" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}">
    </label>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('profile-field', {
      inputBlur: function () {
        console.log('input blurred');
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Oddly, blur and focus do bubble up when captured http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html, though this be interrupted by the shadowDOM, not sure how and doesn't change the answer's correctness, but worth noting as interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For me under Polymer 1.9.1 the *blur* event doesn't fire if the handler is defined with two way binding.
So, I am using the ***on-blur="inputBlur"*** definition instead of ***on-blur="{{inputBlur}}"*** for *blur* event.

```
<paper-input always-float-label
                         label="Some label"
                         required
                         type="number"
                         step="1"
                         min="0"
                         max="4000"
                         value="{{someValueProp}}"        
                         on-blur="inputBlur" 
                         readonly="[[readonly]]"></paper-input>

inputBlur: function () {
     //Some code inside
},
```